# Web service instance creation

Tags: asp.net, web-services, request

Is web service instance creates for every request? Can I declare field in web service and be sure, that it will not be intersected for different users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  mean  ASP.NET then  the threads are reused so if you  declare a variable threadlocal it is still accessible in different requests.
You  can  use  HttpContext.Current.Items for per-request storage.